# Talend tHDFSOutput vs tHDFSPut Components

Tags: talend

This Question is Regarding Talend Big Data Open Studio.

What is the difference between tHDFSOutput and tHDFSPut?

Answer (score 0):

`tHDFSPut` component combines HDFS connection and data extraction, thus usually used as a single-component subjob to move data from a user-defined local directory to HDFS.

`tHDFSOutput` component runs standalone and does not generate input or output flow for the other components.
It is often connected to the Job using OnSubjobOk or OnComponentOk link, depending on the context.

Let me know if this helps.